# Magento in subdirectory of another framework/application

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to use Magento and place it inside of another PHP framework like  Yii in a subdirectory?

We are currently trying to place Magento in `example.com/magento`.

**UPDATE 21/07/2015**

We have managed to make it work but the problem is that the theme, css, js and template is not working or showing. do i need to update something to make it work? thankyou

**UPDATE 22/07/2015**

The problem regarding theme, css, etc not loading is because of the folder in the app/code. in the modules, it was declare as local, but the current file name is local1, so i change it to local and everything is fine..

**UPDATE 23/07/2015**

after fixing everything, i found another problem in here. the magento connect manager is not working. it only displays `The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.` do i need to configure anything? please help me.thank you

Comment: I believe it will be different installation, say two frameworks will live in own folders. The other question is do they need to communicate in some way?

Comment: no, the php framework do not need to communicate with magento.

Comment: Regarding your update: Did you configure the base url in Magento to `example.com/magento/` ?

Comment: If one of the answers helped you solve your original problem, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's possible.
But you will need to uncomment this line from `.htaccess`.

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

And you have to make sure that your other application (build on Yii or something else) does not have urls mapped to the key `magento`.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a conflict if the other framework rewrites all requests to `/index.php` (and most frameworks do this), so that the rewrite rules of Magento do not apply.

Find the line in your root `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And add this **directly before**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento
```

It will exclude all requests starting with `/magento` from the rewrite rule of your other framework (Yii)